# How to override default action when Apps cannot connect to Server?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

The apps shows below screen when the connection to server is unsuccessful, but our customer doesn't wan the user to be able to view the "Details" of the error which I had no idea how to remove it. Can we override the default behaviour and show a custom screen instead?

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you had specified the

```
ConnectOnStartUp=true
```

in initOption js file then on starting up itself it will try to connect with the server , In that case use there will a for connection failure,it will be commented first in init Option.You have to uncomment it in initOption js file and give something to do when the connection has failed in that function . So the error will be customized

Answer (score 1):

You can use WL.Client.Connect API to connect to Worklight server, and use it's onSuccess and onFailure callback functions to show the users whatever you want. More information can be found here: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/t_ConnectingToWorklightServer.html?resultof=%22%63%6f%6e%6e%65%63%74%22%20